# Suppressing dialog messages coming from WFMC_MESSAGES_PROCESS

Tags: abap, sap-erp

Is there a way to suppress/block a dialog from `WFMC_MESSAGES_PROCESS`?
I've tried adding the exceptions below but it doesn't seem to work.

```
CALL FUNCTION 'WFMC_MESSAGES_PROCESS'
 EXPORTING 
   PI_NO_DIALOG  = 'X'
   ...
 EXCEPTIONS
   error_message = 21 ##NUMBER_OK.
```

Thank you!

Comment: I would try IMPORTING parameter PI_NO_DIALOG = 'X' first.

Comment: Hello I did this but the error comes from one of the include that was being used by the fm which is a dialog type A

Comment: There's no general solution for dialogs. It will depend on the exact case, `WFMC_MESSAGES_PROCESS` in your case. I updated your question to precise that, and also that you used `PI_NO_DIALOG = 'X'` as this is essential to mention. Please revert back if you don't agree. NB: the special exception `ERROR_MESSAGE` is only to hide messages displayed using `MESSAGE`.

Comment: give the screenshot of the dialog you wanna suppress

Comment: @Suncatcher I want to suppress any message that has an abend message type.